# Can I move up and down an on-screen page by voice command?

Tags: google-now

Can I move up and down an on-screen page by voice command within Google Now?

Answer (score 2):

According to my knowledge and my researches it seems you can't.
If you want to see all the voice commands you can use check this site below:

https://www.google.it/amp/www.greenbot.com/article/2359684/android/a-list-of-all-the-ok-google-voice-commands.amp.html